# Can multiple workflows re-use persisted DataFrames across separate client processes?

Tags: dask

I have a series of data-preparation jobs that are controlled (scheduled, launched, monitored, etc) by an external system.

These jobs all re-use the same Dask cluster (each process creates a new client).

When job1 finishes and exits, how long would its persisted DataFrames remain in worker memory?

Can job2 get access to DataFrames that were persisted by job1? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When job1 finishes and exists, how long would its persisted DataFrames remain in worker memory?

A few milliseconds.  Dask removes data as soon as no Client has a future pointing to it.

> Can job2 get access to DataFrames that were persisted by job1? If so, how?

Yes.  You're probably looking for the datasets functionality.

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html#distributed.Client.publish_dataset
https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/publish.html

```
# on machine 1
client1.datasets["my-dataset"] = df

# on machine 2
df = client2.datasets["my-dataset"]
```

There are also a variety of other mechanisms for the scheduler to hold onto futures, including Variables, Queues, Pub/Sub, and more.  My guess is that the datasets API is what you're looking for though.